# Labels in a grouped bar chart with multiple groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to show labels in a grouped bar chart. There are a number of answers to this question in stackoverflow which I have tried, but none of them work in my application.

My chart shows a group of bars for two quarters, 2020 Q4 and 2021 Q1. The labels do not appear on top of the bars as they should. I find that when I change the chart to show bars for 2020 Q4 only, or 2021 Q1 only, then the labels appear properly, but when I show both quarters together, for comparison purposes, the labels no longer appear where they should. Here is my reprex. Help appreciated.

```
Date <- as.Date(c("2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01",
  "2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01",
  "2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01",
  "2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01",
  "2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01",
  "2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01"))
GEO <- c(
"Canada","Newfoundland and Labrador","Prince Edward Island",     
"Nova Scotia","New Brunswick","Quebec","Ontario","Manitoba","Saskatchewan",             
"Alberta","British Columbia","Yukon","Northwest Territories","Nunavut",
"Canada","Newfoundland and Labrador","Prince Edward Island","Nova Scotia",              
"New Brunswick","Quebec","Ontario","Manitoba","Saskatchewan","Alberta",                  
"British Columbia","Yukon","Northwest Territories","Nunavut")
JVR <- c(3.5,2.6,3.2,3.3,3.9,4.1,3.4,3.1,2.3,2.4,4.2,4.4,3.0,2.6,
  3.6,2.0,2.5,3.2,3.2,4.2,3.3,3.1,2.7,2.8,4.5,4.7,4.2,3.6)
df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(Date),GEO=GEO,JVR=JVR)
ggplot(filter(df,Date>=as.Date("2020-10-01")),aes(x=Date,y=JVR,fill=GEO)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label=JVR,group=GEO),position=position_dodge(width=0.9),
    vjust=-1,size=3)
```

Comment: `width=90` for the text doge seems about right, but I'm not sure how to get that without trial and error

Answer (score 3):

The `ggfittext` package can help here. If you'd like to have equal text sizes for the labels, you'd probably need to convert them using `format`, otherwise e.g. the number "3" will appear larger than "3.1" to fit in the bar.

**get data**

```r
library(tidyverse)

Date <- as.Date(c("2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01",
                  "2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01",
                  "2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01",
                  "2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01",
                  "2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01",
                  "2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01"))
GEO <- c(
  "Canada","Newfoundland and Labrador","Prince Edward Island",     
  "Nova Scotia","New Brunswick","Quebec","Ontario","Manitoba","Saskatchewan",             
  "Alberta","British Columbia","Yukon","Northwest Territories","Nunavut",
  "Canada","Newfoundland and Labrador","Prince Edward Island","Nova Scotia",              
  "New Brunswick","Quebec","Ontario","Manitoba","Saskatchewan","Alberta",                  
  "British Columbia","Yukon","Northwest Territories","Nunavut")
JVR <- c(3.5,2.6,3.2,3.3,3.9,4.1,3.4,3.1,2.3,2.4,4.2,4.4,3.0,2.6,
         3.6,2.0,2.5,3.2,3.2,4.2,3.3,3.1,2.7,2.8,4.5,4.7,4.2,3.6)
df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(Date),GEO=GEO,JVR=JVR)
```

**plot data**

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfittext)
d.plot <- filter(df,Date>=as.Date("2020-10-01"))

ggplot(d.plot, aes(x=Date,y=JVR,fill=GEO,label=format(JVR, digits = 2))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") +
  # from `ggfittext`
  geom_bar_text(position="dodge",
                place="top",grow=F,reflow=F,min.size=0) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is with the continuous `Date` variable on the x-axis. In your example with `x=Date`, the `position_dodge(width= 0.9)` parameter does not work.

But if you convert the two dates of interest into factors (e.g. `2020 Q4` and `2021 Q1`) the `width = 0.9` parameter works. In this example I think this gives a more meaningful x-axis, so you don't confuse the dodged bars for different dates.

Note `geom_col` is equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`.

```r
# does not work
ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=JVR, fill=GEO)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(aes(label=JVR), position = position_dodge(width = .9))
```

[image]

```r
# works

df %>%
  mutate(quarter = case_when(
    Date == "2020-10-01" ~ '2020 Q4',
    Date == "2021-01-01" ~ '2021 Q1')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=quarter, y=JVR, fill=GEO)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(aes(label=JVR), position = position_dodge(width = .9))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

Data

```
library(tidyverse)

Date <- as.Date(c("2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01",
  "2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01",
  "2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01",
  "2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01",
  "2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01",
  "2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01"))
GEO <- c(
"Canada","Newfoundland and Labrador","Prince Edward Island",     
"Nova Scotia","New Brunswick","Quebec","Ontario","Manitoba","Saskatchewan",             
"Alberta","British Columbia","Yukon","Northwest Territories","Nunavut",
"Canada","Newfoundland and Labrador","Prince Edward Island","Nova Scotia",              
"New Brunswick","Quebec","Ontario","Manitoba","Saskatchewan","Alberta",                  
"British Columbia","Yukon","Northwest Territories","Nunavut")
JVR <- c(3.5,2.6,3.2,3.3,3.9,4.1,3.4,3.1,2.3,2.4,4.2,4.4,3.0,2.6,
  3.6,2.0,2.5,3.2,3.2,4.2,3.3,3.1,2.7,2.8,4.5,4.7,4.2,3.6)
df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(Date),GEO=GEO,JVR=JVR)
```

Comment: upvoted because of the more meaningful x-axis.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Three quite different solutions, all of them doing the trick.